# How to convert command line code to simple code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

So, I am trying to pass a code to main(), the original code is command line based (It takes arguments from command line interface) but I want to pass it to main() directly in program. Here is the original code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_fmt = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=log_fmt)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('json_in')
    parser.add_argument('graph_out')
    parser.add_argument('text_out')
    parser.add_argument('spm_model')
    parser.add_argument('--sequence', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--simple-preprocessing',
                        action='store_false', dest='extended_preprocessing')
    parser.add_argument('--bpe-dropout', type=float, default=None)
    parser.add_argument('--sample-factor', type=int, default=1)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

Now I understand how to convert each line except 11th one, line including the `--sequence`.

I don't understand what to pass for `dest` in program.

I am actually working on colab and it throws as error `SystemExit: 2`  with `argparse`, thats why I dont want to use it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The flags with a `-` prefix, are accessed by removing the `-` prefix and making the non-prefix `-` underscores `_`, if there is no `dest` defined.

```py
parser.add_argument('--sequence', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--simple-preprocessing',
                    action='store_false', dest='extended_preprocessing')
parser.add_argument('--bpe-dropout', type=float, default=None)
parser.add_argument('--sample-factor', type=int, default=1)

args = parser.parse_args()

args.sequence 
args.extended_preprocessing     # use dest
args.bpe_dropout
args.sample_factory
```

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate your quick answer, but the problem is I dont want to use arguments(args). Like I want to use pass these values in main directly!! 

as an example: json_in = 'link to file'

I am trying to run this code on Colab actually.

Comment: you could make an object that works the same as the args object and use that instead, but maybe rewriting the signature to main makes more sense.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Args:
    sequence = False
    extended_preprocessing = False
    bpe_dropout = None
    sample_factor = 1

args = Args(sequence=True, sample_factor = 3)

main(args)
```

but maybe you want to rewrite `main` to take the arguments separately.

```
def main(sequence: bool, extend_preprocessing: bool, bpe_dropout: float, sample_factor: int) - > None:
    ....
```